# "No service is hosted at the specified address" when accessing Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1

Tags: servicebus

[Cross-posted on [Azure forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/367ff53e-a6bb-4c84-92fc-8a5b4c77b9d3/no-service-is-hosted-at-the-specified-address-when-accessing-sb-11?forum=servbus) because I didn't get any answer there]

Hi,

I've installed Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 Preview on my Windows 8 Pro dev machine with SQL Express. My account is local administrator.

Although checking if a queue exists seems to work (at least, not generating any error), I got an exception when trying to create a queue, saying "No service is hosted at the specified address".

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

**UPDATE:** So the lack of domain is definitely not an issue as I have followed [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj714802%28v=azure.10%29.aspx#BMK_SBDev2). I'm also sure that my authentication data is correct as the call to `.QueueExists()` fails if I change my password, for example.

Still, I get the following exception when calling `.CreateQueue()`:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingEntityNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : 
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical">
  <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier>
  <Description>Unhandled exception</Description>
  <AppDomain>ServiceBusTest.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
  <Exception>
    <ExceptionType>Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingEntityNotFoundException, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</ExceptionType>
    <Message>The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. No service is hosted at the specified address..TrackingId:ab98e78f-5bd0-43df-92dc-5703b9f7f5e1_GAdditive,TimeStamp:10/13/13 8:45:46 AM</Message>
    <StackTrace>   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.OnEndCreateQueue(IAsyncResult result)
      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.EndCreateQueue(IAsyncResult result)
      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateQueue(QueueDescription description)
      at ServiceBusTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ServiceBusTest\ServiceBusTest\Program.cs:line 40
      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
      at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace>
    <ExceptionString>The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. No service is hosted at the specified address..TrackingId:ab98e78f-5bd0-43df-92dc-5703b9f7f5e1_GAdditive,TimeStamp:10/13/13 8:45:46 AM</ExceptionString>
    <DataItems>
      <Data><Key>DisablePrepareForRethrow</Key><Value></Value></Data>
      <Data><Key>Microsoft.ServiceBus</Key><Value>Microsoft.ServiceBus</Value></Data>
    </DataItems>
    <InnerException>
      <ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
      <Message>The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.</Message>
      <StackTrace>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1.&amp;lt;GetAsyncSteps&amp;gt;b__14(CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
      </StackTrace>
      <ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ServiceBusResourceOperations.CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1.&amp;lt;GetAsyncSteps&amp;gt;b__14(CreateOrUpdateAsyncResult`1 thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
        at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
      </ExceptionString>
    </InnerException>
  </Exception>
</TraceRecord>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it finally turned out that the latest version of the Service Bus client library (Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll v2.1.3) is not compatible with Service Bus for Windows Server v1.1 Preview... Switching back to v2.0.1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I followed the sample code on MSDN and I had exactly the same error. I spent an hour trying to find what the issue is, then I found this [post](http://www.mstechbits.com/azure/servicebus/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-404-not-found-no-service-is-hosted-at-the-specified-address-microsoft-servicebus-messaging-messagingentitynotfoundexception/), which explains the problem. Basically, you need to install the Service Bus 1.0 Nuget package not the 1.1 version, that causes some incompatibility issues. The text below is quoted from the helpful blog post

> One solution for the issue is to either follow the instructions as
>   provided in the MSDN article to upgrade to “Windows Azure Pack:
>   Service Bus 1.1“ which involves uninstalling the Service Bus for
>   Windows 1.0 and use Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll with version 2.1.0.0.
>
> The other solution is to remove the Nuget Package (ServiceBus 1.1 for
>   Windows Server) and install the (ServiceBus 1.0 for Windows Server)
>   which would add the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll with version 1.8.0.0.

I have put the details of my sample code (setup, sending, and receiving messages) in a blog post [here](http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/getting-started-with-service-bus-azure-and-windows-server-with-samples/)